# Making permanent change in a dataframe using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I would like to convert y dataframe from one format (X:XX:XX:XX) of values to another (X.X seconds)

Here is my dataframe looks like:

```
            Start         End
    0  0:00:00:00                 
    1  0:00:00:00  0:07:37:80     
    2  0:08:08:56  0:08:10:08     
    3  0:08:13:40                       
    4  0:08:14:00  0:08:14:84    
 
And I would like to transform it in seconds, something like that

        Start         End
    0     0.0         
    1     0.0      457.80
    2  488.56      490.80
    3  493.40
    4   494.0      494.84
```

To do that I did:

```
i = 0
j = 0

while j < 10:
    while i < 10:
        if data.iloc[i, j] != "":
            Value = (int(data.iloc[i, j][0]) * 3600) + (int(data.iloc[i, j][2:4]) *60) + int(data.iloc[i, j][5:7]) + (int(data.iloc[i, j][8: 10])/100)
            NewValue = data.iloc[:, j].replace([data.iloc[i, j]], Value)
            i += 1
        else:
            NewValue = data.iloc[:, j].replace([data.iloc[i, j]], "")
            i += 1
        data.update(NewValue)
    i = 0
    j += 1
```

But I failed to replace the new values in my oldest dataframe in a permament way, when I do:

```
print(data)
```

I still get my old data frame in the wrong format.

Some one could hep me? I tried so hard!

Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `pandas.DataFrame.update` that requires a pandas dataframe as an argument. See the Example part of the update function documentation to really understand what update does https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html

If I may suggest a more idiomatic solution; you can directly map a function to all values of a pandas Series

```
def parse_timestring(s):
    if s == "":
        return s
    else:
        # weird to use centiseconds and not milliseconds
        # l is a list with [hour, minute, second, cs]
        l = [int(nbr) for nbr in s.split(":")]
        return sum([a*b for a,b in zip(l, (3600, 60, 1, 0.01))])

df["Start"] = df["Start"].map(parse_timestring)
```

You can remove the `if ... else ...` from `parse_timestring` if you replace all empty string with nan values in your dataframe with `df = df.replace("", numpy.nan)` then use `df["Start"] = df["Start"].map(parse_timestring, na_action='ignore')`

see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html

Answer (score 0):

The `datetime`library is made to deal with such data. You should also use the `apply` function of pandas to avoid iterating on the dataframe like that.
You should proceed as follow :

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def to_seconds(date):
    comp = date.split(':')
    delta =  (datetime.strptime(':'.join(comp[1:]),"%H:%M:%S") - datetime(1900, 1, 1)) +    timedelta(days=int(comp[0]))
    return delta.total_seconds()
    

data['Start'] = data['Start'].apply(to_seconds)
data['End']   = data['End'].apply(to_seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help.
Your method was working. I also found a method using loop:

To summarize, my general problem was that I had an ugly csv file that I wanted to transform is a csv usable for doing statistics, and to do that I wanted to use python.
my csv file was like:

```
    MiceID = 1    Beginning          End   Type of behavior
0                0:00:00:00                     Video start
1                0:00:01:36                 grooming type 1   
2                0:00:03:18                 grooming type 2
3                0:00:06:73    0:00:08:16   grooming type 1
```

So in my ugly csv file I was writing only the moment of the begining of the behavior type without the end when the different types of behaviors directly followed each other, and I was writing the moment of the end of the behavior when the mice stopped to make any grooming, that allowed me to separate sequences of grooming. But this type of csv was not usable for easily making statistics.
So I wanted 1) transform all my value in seconds to have a correct format, 2) then I wanted to fill the gap in the end colonne (a gap has to be fill with the following begining value, as the end of a specific behavior in a sequence is the begining of the following), 3) then I wanted to create columns corresponding to the duration of each behavior, and finally 4) to fill this new column with the duration.

My questionning was about the first step, but I put here the code for each step separately:

step 1: transform the values in a good format

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



data = pd.read_csv("D:/Python/TestPythonTraitementDonnéesExcel/RawDataBatch2et3.csv", engine = "python")

data.replace(np.nan, "", inplace = True)

i = 0
j = 0 

while j < len(data.columns):
    while i < len(data.index):
        if (":" in data.iloc[i, j]) == True:
            Value = str((int(data.iloc[i, j][0]) * 3600) + (int(data.iloc[i, j][2:4]) *60) + int(data.iloc[i, j][5:7]) + (int(data.iloc[i, j][8: 10])/100))
            data = data.replace([data.iloc[i, j]], Value)
            data.update(data)
            i += 1
        else:
            i += 1
    i = 0
    j += 1

print(data)
```

step 2: fill the gaps

```
i = 0
j = 2

while j < len(data.columns): 
    while i < len(data.index) - 1:
        if data.iloc[i, j] == "":
            data.iloc[i, j] = data.iloc[i + 1, j - 1]
            data.update(data)
            i += 1
        elif np.all(data.iloc[i:len(data.index), j] == ""):
            break
        else:
            i += 1
    i = 0
    j += 4
print(data)
```

step 3: create a new colunm for each mice:

```
j = 1
k = 0

while k < len(data.columns) - 1:
    k = (j * 4) + (j - 1)
    data.insert(k, "Duree{}".format(k), "")
    data.update(data)
    j += 1 

print(data)
```

step 3: fill the gaps

```
j = 4
i = 0

while j < len(data.columns):
    while i < len(data.index):
        if data.iloc[i, j - 2] != "":
            data.iloc[i, j] = str(float(data.iloc[i, j - 2]) - float(data.iloc[i, j - 3]))
            data.update(data)
            i += 1
        else:
            break
    i = 0
    j += 5

print(data)
```

And of course, export my new usable dataframe

```
data.to_csv(r"D:/Python/TestPythonTraitementDonnéesExcel/FichierPropre.csv", index = False, header = True)
```

here are the transformations:
click on the links for the pictures

[before step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3jR4.png)

[after step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu0nq.png)

[after step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R7af.png)

[after step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsPlN.png)

[after step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5zTt.png)